# Discretizing the Wave Equation in polar coordinates

Tags: waves, discrete, computational-physics, numerical-method

I want to discretize the wave equation

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\psi\left(\vec{r},t\right)}{\partial t^2}=\triangle\psi\left(\vec{r},t\right)$$

in polar coordinates. I find the following relations:

$$\vec{r}=r\mathbf{e}_r$$
$$\triangle=\frac{1}{r}\partial_r r \partial_r+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_\varphi^2$$

Define:

$$r=i\Delta r,\qquad\varphi=j\Delta\varphi,\qquad t=n\Delta t$$

Thus:

$$\psi\left(r,\varphi,t\right)=\psi\left(i\Delta r,j\Delta \varphi,n\Delta t\right)\equiv\psi_{i,j}^{\left(n\right)}$$

Using the forward difference in $r$ and central differences in $\varphi$ and $t$, I get:

$$\psi_{i,j}^{\left(n+1\right)}=2\psi_{i,j}^{\left(n\right)}-\psi_{i,j}^{\left(n-1\right)}+\frac{c^2 \Delta t^2}{\Delta r^2}\left[\psi_{i+2,j}^{\left(n\right)}+\frac{1}{i}\psi_{i+2,j}^{\left(n\right)}-2\psi_{i+1,j}^{\left(n\right)}-\frac{1}{i}\psi_{i+1,j}^{\left(n\right)}+\psi_{i,j}^{\left(n\right)}\right]+\frac{c^2\Delta t^2}{i^2\Delta r^2\Delta \varphi^2}\left[\psi_{i,j+1}^{\left(n\right)}+\psi_{i,j-1}^{\left(n\right)}-2\psi_{i,j}^{\left(n\right)}\right]$$

Now this is divergent at $r=0$, did I something wrong?

And how can I set restrictions to the steps $\Delta r$, $\Delta \varphi$ and $\Delta t$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the Laplacian:
$$
\nabla^2=\frac{1}{r}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}
$$
you can clearly see that *this* diverges at $r=0$ so discretization of this should *also* diverge.

There are three solutions to remedying the divergent feature that I can think of:

1. Choose a problem such that you don't need to worry about $r=0$ (e.g., $r_{min}=0.1$)
2. Use cell-centered values for $r$ (e.g., $r_{min}=\frac12dr$)
3. Use two meshes a Cartesian one for $r<1$ and a polar one for $r\geq1$, merging them at $r\simeq1$ (requires at least 1 cell of overlap).

I've never used option #3, so I cannot speak anything about it. Option #1 works in certain cases, but not for all. Option #2 I *have* worked with and have seen in other hydrodynamics codes that I've used, so it might be your best bet.

---

As far as your discretization goes, I think it might be more clear to use $r_i$ and $\phi_j$ for the positions and $dr$ and $d\phi$ for the cell widths. Using this,
$$
\frac{1}{r}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{1}{r_i}\left(r_{i+1/2}\frac{\psi^n_{i+1,j}-\psi^n_{i,j}}{dr^2}-r_{i-1/2}\frac{\psi^n_{i,j}-\psi^n_{i-1,j}}{dr^2}\right)
\\
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial\phi^2}=\frac{1}{r_i^2}\left(\frac{\psi^n_{i,j+1}-2\psi^n_{i,j}+\psi^n_{i,j-1}}{d\phi^2}\right)
$$
where $r_{i+1/2}=\frac12\left(r_{i+1}+r_i\right)$.

Your choice for $dr$ and $d\phi$ are up to you. It *might* be easier to have $dr=d\phi$, but it might not be worth enforcing that behavior. The timestep, however, is limited by the [Courant-Friedrichs-Levy condition](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=courant+friedrichs+lewy&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest). For the wave equation, your requirement is such that
$$
c^2\frac{dt}{\min(dr^2,d\phi^2)}\leq\frac12
$$
Formally, the constant can be 1 instead of $\frac12$, but for multidimensional systems, it is appropriate to use $1/n_{dim}$. For time-stepping purposes, this is going to be the slow point of your code. It might be worth looking into [implicit methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Implicit_method) instead of the explicit method you are currently working with.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
but I have some questions:
1) Does Option #2 ensure continuity at $r=0$?
2) Why does the CFL-condition not contain the wave speed? And why the maximum of $dr^2$ and $d\phi^2$?
3) Actually, I have to simulate a drum. It's a problem with polar symmetry, could I leave out the dependence of $\phi$?

Comment: (1) it will so long as your scheme will conserve it. (2) it should contain $c^2$, I just forgot it. You want the max to ensure the diffusion is appropriately captured. (3) you might be able to, but I cannot tell you for sure.

Comment: @Andy: Actually, scratch that. You do want the minimum because the CFL conditions tells you how far something can be advected/diffused out of the cell before it is unphysical. Using the minimum of the two ensures that the physics is contained in the cell.