# Solving Poisson equation for galaxy rotation curves

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, computational-physics, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

Can someone point me to the numerical methods to solve the Poisson equation for the galaxy rotation curves?
I've heard of some tools like PETSc or OpenFOAM. But I'm not sure if these are the right tools for calculating galaxy rotation curves.

Calculation of velocity as $v^2(R) = \frac{ G}{R}M(R)$, where $M(R)$ is the galactic mass till radius $R$, seems too simplified with the assumption of mass distribution having spatial symmetry. So, I'm looking for numerical solution of the Poisson equation, for more accurate results.

Also, I believe, one needs to solve the galaxy rotation curve n 3D to get reasonable results. 2D solutions may be misleading, even though the galaxy is mostly a disc. I'm thinking this because the gravitational field would be in 3D, and restricting the gravitational field to 2D may be erroneous.

Comment: Why do you need the Poisson equation? Isn't it just $v^2\sim\nabla\phi(r)$?

Comment: To determine $\phi$ using the Poisson equation, $\nabla^2 \phi = 4\pi G\rho$.

Comment: Okay, so you don't want to start with potential models (Miyamoto-Nagai, Plummer, etc) and get the velocity profile from those potentials. But even still, wouldn't it just be integrating the (radial) mass density so that you end up with $\nabla\phi$ that you can plug in directly?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos That suggestion would be a 2D model, which wont work.. Let us take $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} = 2 \pi G \rho$. This gives $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \frac{2\pi G}{r}\int r\rho dr$. For $\rho = e^{-r}$,, this gives $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \frac{2\pi G}{r}(1 + r) (1 - e^{-r})$. This will not lead to a decaying velocity. The reason being that we are now constraining the gravity in 2D space. The rectification for the above would be to model $\rho(r, z) = e^{-r}\delta(z)$. But this is then 3D, and z is now included.

Comment: I'm now confused. If your interest is in a *radial* profile, why does the height of the galaxy matter? An axisymmetric profile in the radial direction should suffice, no? If not, you can have dozens of potentials that already exist in literature that can well-describe a galaxy (cf. [this page](https://home.ifa.hawaii.edu/users/barnes/ast626_97/gp.html) or [this one](https://www.astro.utu.fi/~cflynn/galdyn/lecture4.html), among many).

Answer (score 0):

When solving the Poisson equation numerically, you can use any programming language that allows for multi-dimensional arrays (C/C++, Fortran, Rust, Python, ....). While I imagine OpenFOAM and PETSc can be used, they are not required.<sup>1</sup>

You have a relatively simple PDE that you can apply [discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization) to use in a numerical model. In this way, your PDE would appear as, assuming a cylindrical model,<sup>2</sup>
\begin{align}\nabla^2\Phi\triangleq &
\frac{1}{r_i}\left(r_{i+1/2}\frac{\Phi_{i+1,j,k}-\Phi_{i,j,k}}{dr^2}-r_{i-1/2}\frac{\Phi_{i,j,k}-\Phi_{i-1,j,k}}{dr^2}\right) \\ &\quad+\frac{1}{r_i^2}\frac{\Phi_{i,j+1,k}+\Phi_{i,j-1,k}-2\Phi_{i,j,k}}{d\phi^2}\\
&\quad+\frac{\Phi_{i,j,k+1}+\Phi_{i,j,k-1}-2\Phi_{i,j,k}}{dz^2}=\rho(r_i,\,\phi_j,\,z_k)\tag{1}
\end{align}
This would require a 3D array for $\Phi$ and some [tricks for handling $r\simeq0$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/112906/25301). Note that under axial symmetry, the middle term vanishes as,
$$\Phi_{i,j+1,k}=\Phi_{i,j-1,k}=\Phi_{i,j,k},$$
which would require only a 2D array to solve since $j$ index wouldn't matter anymore. In either case, you need to solve Equation (1) for $\Phi_{i,j,k}$, which can then be used in a [relaxation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(iterative_method)) (or any of the "See also" links in this Wikipedia entry) to find the potential to the given density profile.

Once you have that solution, you can use the same discretization to determine the velocity profile,
$$v(r_i)^2\simeq r_i\frac{\Phi_{i+1,j,k}-\Phi_{i-1,j,k}}{2\cdot dr}.$$
where the $j$ and $k$ indices on $\Phi$ would either be used to average over all heights or for a single slice.

---

<sup>1. My proverbial \$0.02 would be to *not* use those modules as knowing how to numerically solve PDEs and ODEs is a good tool to have in your possession.</sup>

<sup>2. For spherical systems, the radial term is of the form $r^{-2}\partial_r\left(r^2\partial_r\Phi\right)$; most sources I've seen prefer writing it as the split operator, $\partial^2_r\Phi+\frac{2}{r}\partial_r\Phi$, and deriving the finite difference stencil from that. It might be easier to just use Cartesian coordinates and compute the spherical/cylindrical/etc coordinates from the positions when computing the mass density.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll check what you sent. But I would need 3D arrays I think

Comment: For a non-axisymmetric scenario, yes that would be correct. It's otherwise identical to what I'd described.

Comment: For reference, the link on the "tricks for handling $r\simeq0$" discusses the $r$-$\phi$ system, so you'd have a reference for the third dimension of the Laplacian. Do you have a full 3D density profile of a galaxy to use in this?

Comment: Even if the galaxy profile is 2D, I dont see think the gravity potential model in 2D is correct. For, example, the one I've derived analytically in a comment above $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \frac{2\pi G}{r}(1+r)(1 - e^{-r})$ for $\rho = e^{-r}$, which is definitely not the right answer. Even if $\rho$ is 2D, gravity field is 3D.

Comment: How do you compare the relaxation technique you have mentioned above with using FFT? One thought though is that I may need cartesian co-ordinates for FFT, as the FFT of Laplacian in polar co-ord may be tricky.

Comment: On the 3D v/s 2D, for example, in the link you gave, if you see the Axisymmetric potential section, the Kuzmin potential is present in z dimension (3D), even though rho is purely radial.

Comment: $r$ is a single dimension, so using $\rho=\mathrm{e}^{-r}$ is 1D, not 2D. But I'm still confused about what your problem is with any of the formulae you've presented, what isn't right about it? For FFT, I don't use it b/c the problems I've faced are more suited for $n$D-arrays. I don't know which link has Kuzmin profile in it, but technically it follows $\rho(r,z)=\Sigma(r)\delta(z)$ *by design*.

Comment: $r\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}$ should decrease with $r$, and not increase. Also, $r$ may be a unidimensional variable, but once you use $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} r \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}$ as Laplacian, you are actually doing 2D, not 1D.

Comment: Okay, assuming you are solving the PDE correctly (I haven't bothered checking), but wouldn't an increasing velocity profile tell you that the mass density profile isn't correct? Perhaps this is the reason why galaxy models prefer $1/f(r)$ instead of $\mathrm{e}^{-r}$?

Comment: Assume a given point mass, $M$,  and a uniform gravitational field in $n$ dimensions. Then, from Gauss law, gravity field = $G \propto \frac{M}{r^n}$. Thus in higher dimensions, the field will decay faster. Thus, in 2D, the field will decay slower than in 3D. The gravitational field in a galaxy is inherently 3D, even though the mass distribution can be approximated as a disk. A 2D modeling would be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, a 2D model wouldn't be formally correct since the real world is 3D, however approximations are allowed in physics and often yield good results/explanations. In either event, I've adapted the answer to address 3D Laplacian.